# C++ Boost.Python : 2 problems

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

So, i search good tool to integrate my C++ code with python, and at first i looked at boost.python.

I've get hello examle from boost documentation and try to build and run it. Source code is (src/hello.cpp):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

**Problem 1 - Windows and mingw**

I try to build and my result :

```
g++ -o build\hello.o -c -IE:\Programming\libs\boost_1_48_0 -IE:\Programming\Python\include src\hello.cpp
g++ -shared -o pyhello.dll build\hello.o -LE:\Programming\libs\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib -LE:\Programming\Python\libs -lboost_python-mgw45-mt-1_48 -lpython27 -Wl,--out-implib,libpyhello.a
Creating library file: libpyhello.a
build\hello.o:hello.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleEPKcPFvvE'
```

Also similar 4 undefined errors with boost::python.

My build boost command line : `bjam toolset=gcc variant=release`

I found similar troubles in google (and on stackoverflow too), but didn't found answer at my case.

**Problem 2 - Using module (linux)**

At linux platform i've no problem with building module, same source compiled well :

```
g++ -o build/hello.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 src/hello.cpp
g++ -o libpyhello.so -shared build/hello.os -lboost_python -lpython2.7
```

Now, how can i use that? In documentation no words about module naming, quote :

> can be exposed to Python by writing a Boost.Python wrapper:
>
> ```
> #include <boost/python.hpp>
>
> BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
> {
>     using namespace boost::python;
>     def("greet", greet);
> }
> ```
>
> That's it. We're done. We can now build this as a shared library. The
>   resulting DLL is now visible to Python. Here's a sample Python
>   session:
>
> ```
> >>> import hello_ext
> >>> print hello_ext.greet()
> hello, world
> ```

So, my module named: libpyhello.so, but how i can use it in python iterpreter? I try import pyhello, hello_ext, libpyhello - and only with libpyhello interpreter is printed :

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initlibpyhello)
```

All other variants of import failed with : `ImportError: No module named pyhello`

**UPDATE 2nd question** : Solved, *.so module must be named as ID used in BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE. After i change : `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)` to `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libpyhello)`, module is imported well as libpyhello.

Comment: You should self-answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's important that the library file is named like you declare the module here:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
```

that is `hello_ext.dll` or `hello_ext.so`.

Comment: This was my problem, my .so was prefix with `_` and my BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE call was not. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem only, that having the module name the same as the libname does not seem to solve the issue. Any other ideas? When I ran nm on the lib I don't see to many symbols inside it, maybe python needs everything to be linked in?

Comment: @MaxShifrin Maybe you need to post another question then. If you do, please add details about why the answers given here don't work/apply to your problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. Building on macOS with cmake, you get hello_ext.dylib, but python looks for hello_ext.so, so you have to rename the built library.

Answer (score 3):

Hi，I have got the same problem as yours under `win7 32bit` with `mingw`， however I fixed it at last.

**The possible solution is：**

**When build the lib boost python, use link=shared instead.**

like:

```
bjam stage toolset=gcc --with-python link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared variant=release,debug --user-config=user-config.jam cxxflags="-include cmath "
```

When link，use the BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB macro explicitly

The following is the sample *cmd* line：

```
g++ hello_ext.cpp -shared -O3 -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -lboost_python  -lpython25 -o hello_ext.pyd
```

To save your time，just add some lines in file `boost\python.hpp`：

```
#include <cmath>   //fix  cmath:1096:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared
#if defined(__MINGW32__) && defined(_WIN32)
#if !defined(BOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE)
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#endif 
#endif 
... here,other includes files ...
```

Then, you can simply use *cmd* like this:

```
g++ hello_ext.cpp -shared -lboost_python  -lpython25 -o hello_ext.pyd
```

This shell will be ok, have a try.